# Using MathJax I need a solution for \ensuremath

Tags: latex, mathjax

I'm using a [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org) in several projects and it generally works like a charm.

Today, however, I ran into a problem during the translation of a part of an existing LaTeX document with the following align-environment:

```
\begin{align}
  & (\lambda x.(\lambda y.(\lambda z.xyz)))abc \\
= & \text{\{ impliciete toepassing expliciet maken \}} \\
  & (((\lambda x.(\lambda y.(\lambda z.xyz)))a)b)c \\
= & \text{\{ \ensuremath{\beta}-reductie, substitutie van \ensuremath{x}door \ensuremath{a}\}} \\
  & ((\lambda y.(\lambda z.ayz))b)c \\
= & \{\text{\ensuremath{\beta}-reductie, \ensuremath{y\,:=b}}\} \\
  & (\lambda z.abz)c \\
= & \text{\{ \ensuremath{\beta}-reductie, \ensuremath{z\,:=c}} \\
 & abc \\ \boxed{} \end{align}
```

The result rendered with LaTeX is this (sorry for the Dutch text ;-):

[image]

The align-environment is essentially a `math` context, so if you want *text*, you need to enclose that text with `\text{...}`. But when you need again math symbols *within* that text, you escape the `text` context by enclosing the maths with `\ensuremath{...}`.

And MathJax renders it like:

[image]

That Mathjax centers everything doesn't matter, that is something I can handle with CSS.  But the rendering of `\ensuremath` is a problem.  Clearly MathJax [doesn't support](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html?highlight=supported) `\ensuremath`, but I can't think of a workable workaround where I can use math symbols in a `text`-context.

Ideally I'ld like to have a solution using an alternative LaTeX construction (hence the cross listing)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$...$` or `\(...\)` in place of `\ensuremath{...}`.  This seems more natural to me even in LaTeX itself (as `\ensuremath` is really designed for use within macros that might be used inside both text- and math-modes).

So you can do

```
\begin{align}
  & (\lambda x.(\lambda y.(\lambda z.xyz)))abc \\
= & \{\text{ impliciete toepassing expliciet maken }\} \\
  & (((\lambda x.(\lambda y.(\lambda z.xyz)))a)b)c \\
= & \{\text{ $\beta$-reductie, substitutie van $x$door $a$ }\} \\
  & ((\lambda y.(\lambda z.ayz))b)c \\
= & \{\text{ $\beta$-reductie, $y:=b$ }\} \\
  & (\lambda z.abz)c \\
= & \{\text{ $\beta$-reductie, $z:=c$ }\} \\
  & abc \\ \boxed{} \end{align}
```

I also put the `\{` and `\}` outside the `\text{}`, though you can do them inside if you prefer.

The centering is probably due to CSS on your page, as MathJax left-justifies these by default.

Comment: Hi @Davide Cervone,  your solution is brilliant in its simplicity and LaTeX appropriateness (if that is a word ;-). Many thanks, it saves my project. And I'm learning a bit more about LaTeX even though I'm using it now for years.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.  Don't forget to accept the answer as correct (if you feel it is), so that your question will be marked as answered.